# Formtastic change style of input boxes on validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, formtastic

I am using the formtastic gem to generate the forms for my project. Rather than display an inline error I would prefer to change the style of the input boxes. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with just css.  Formtastic has an "error" class.  You can change the style of inputs inside this class:

```
form.formtastic fieldset > ol > li.error input{ /** your style here **/ }
```

Then you can change the style of the inline-errors class to display none:

```
form.formtastic fieldset > ol > li p.inline-errors{ display:none; }
```